# Using boto (v1) how can I copy_key with SSE-S3 encryption?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I've used copy_key but to copy a file that is already encrypted with SSE-S3, but copying it unencrypts the file for some reason. How do I ensure it gets copied with SSE-S3?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Server Side Encryption is used with Amazon S3, data is **encrypted at rest**. This means that the data is encrypted before it is stored to disk and is decrypted when read from disk. You will never see the encrypted version of the object.

If you want to copy an object with `copy_key()` and have the destination object encrypted, set the `storage_class` to `REDUCED_REDUNDANCY`.